# Google geocoder issue on form submit

Tags: forms, google-geocoder

I have a problem with Google Geocoder API.

I have a form where the user type a full address. When the form is submited, I want to extract the city from this address and put this city in a hidden field.

So here is what I've done...

HTML :

```
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" onSubmit="codeAddress()">                   
                    <p>
                        <label for="adresse_de_depart">Adresse de départ</label><br />
                        <input type="text" id="adresse_de_depart" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="adresse_de_depart"/>
                    </p>

                    <input type="hidden" id="ville_depart" name="ville_depart" value=""/>

                    <p align="right">
                        <input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" />
                    </p>
                                        </form>
```

JS :

```
<script>
    var geocoder;
     $(document).ready(function(){  
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     });

  function codeAddress() {
    var adresse = document.getElementById("adresse_de_depart").value;

    console.log(geocoder);
    alert(adresse_de_depart);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': adresse}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert("OK");
        document.getElementById("ville_depart").value=results;
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
   }</script>
```

The first "alert" works but after the page is reloaded (and the form is submited). But I have no alert related to the geocode method...

Have you got an idea ?

Thanks !